# Eclipse for C: Launch failed no binaries

Tags: c, windows, eclipse, binary

I know there are a lot of topics to this problem but I have read most of them and still get nothing compiled.

I use Windows 7 and want to program C in Eclipse. So far I installed gcc/g++ 4.8.1, GNU Make 3.82.90.

I set my Path variable to:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin;C:\MinGW\bin;C\msys\1.0\bin

and JAVA_HOME to:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_45

Inside Eclipse I use as Binary Parser Cygwin PE Parser and selected PATH in the environment settings.

Nontheless I get the same error message "Launch failed no binaries" and build project returns:

```
**** Build of configuration Debug for project nhn ****

**** Internal Builder is used for build               ****
Nothing to build for nhn
```

This is all I was able to find, help please!

Comment: Mixing Cygwin and MinGW can cause you grief. I don't know if that's the problem, but I'd recommend using only one of them (and if you're using Cygwin, adding it to the path might help).

Comment: When I create a new C Project the only Toolchain I can use is MinGW GCC. My Path looks like this now: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin;C:\MinGW\bin;C\msys\1.0\bin;C:\cygwin\bin and I get the same error.

Comment: I also deleted MinGW and its existence in Path. Now I have nothing on my toolchain in Eclipse.

Comment: Sorry for asking this, but did you triple-check, that running configuration is ok? I have already lost count how many times I had problems with that. Also you can find the binary and launch it manually, for example from command line. This way you will be sure that the binary is fine and the only problem is Eclipse configuration.

Comment: When I launch my code manually, I get following error code: gcc -oPrioQueue.exe src\PrioQueue.o
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/lib/libmingw32.a(main.o): In function `main':
e:\p\giaw\src\pkg\mingwrt-4.0.3-1-mingw32-src\bld/../mingwrt-4.0.3-1-mingw32-src/src/libcrt/crt/main.c:91: undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Answer (score 0):

With C/C++ its best to use MinGW rather than Cygwin.  I normally work with C++, but C should be fine.  Try reinstalling MinGW and check that the discovery include directories are:

```
C:\MinGW\lib\gcc\i686-pc-mingw32\4.8.0\include
C:\MinGW\lib\gcc\i686-pc-mingw32\4.8.0\include-fixed
C:\MinGW\i686-pc-mingw32\include
```

toolchain:

```
MinGW GCC
```

Binary Parser:

```
PE Windows Parser
```

Comment: Hey, I got a default Hello World C project compiled and it printed Hello World. When I create a custom project with the same Hello World code, it doesn't work and I get above error message. What does the default project have that the custom doesn't?

Comment: Okay, here is the error code when I try to execute my own code. c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/lib/libmingw32.a(main.o): In function `main':
e:\p\giaw\src\pkg\mingwrt-4.0.3-1-mingw32-src\bld/../mingwrt-4.0.3-1-mingw32-src/src/libcrt/crt/main.c:91: undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status